# Difference between navigationClick(),invocAction() & FieldChangeListener() for any Field in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I am confused when i have to use navigationClick(),invocAction() or FieldChangeListener().
And which one is best suitable for non-touch and touch Devices.

Plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the change listener gets called every time every the field is changed, for example every single character input would call the listener even if you are still inputing info.

Not much, but I wish I have helped ;)

Comment: So if i am adding some thing in editfield then at that time fieldchacgelistener is called. Am i right?

Comment: yep, every character, backspace, tab will call it.

Comment: Then why only on click the fieldchangelistener invokes.